# Make left and right screen widgets stay in the same place while user scrolls down the page with spacebar

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I have webpage with a large height attribute which displays products.  I want the user to hit space bar to move the page down to view more products, but I need my screen widgets (shopping cart & categories) on the left and right to stay in the same place on the screen.  And I don't want to use scrollbars.  I assume this is a javascript request, can someone point me to a good resource for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to use JavaScript here - CSS should do. Using `position: fixed`, you can fix the elements in your page such that they always remain in a certain position relative to the user's viewport. An example would probably illustrate this best: http://www.jsfiddle.net/yijiang/qtkss/

Further reading:

- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/displaypositionfloat
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/display
- http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/

Answer (score 2):

You don't need javascript for this, just use `position: fixed;` in the widget's CSS and set the appropriate `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` values on the widgets. That will position the widgets in a fixed location with respect to the browser window rather than other elements in the HTML.